# WP_Query load the selected post

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to load a selected post in a ajax function, I have some problems writing the appropriate query that calls the post i'm pointing

```
<?php
 $pb_id = $_POST['post_id'];
 $pb_details_args = array(
   'p' => $pb_id,
  );

 $pb_details_query = new WP_Query( $pb_details_args );

while ($pb_details_query -> have_post() ):
  $pb_details_query -> the_post();
  echo '<h4>' . get_the_title() . '</h4>';
endwhile
?>
```

at the moment i have this piece of code but i think is basically entirely wrong, can you help me?

Comment: [get_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/)?

Comment: with this function. Answer below explains how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just title, you can go with:

```
<?php
echo get_the_title($_POST['post_id']);
?>
```

that will give you jsut post title.If you need everything else:

```
<?php
$single_post = get_post( $_POST['post_id'] ); 
echo $single_post->post_title; // title
?>
```

Full reference:

```
WP_Post Object
(
    [ID] =>
    [post_author] =>
    [post_date] => 
    [post_date_gmt] => 
    [post_content] => 
    [post_title] => 
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] =>
    [comment_status] =>
    [ping_status] => 
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] =>
    [to_ping] => 
    [pinged] => 
    [post_modified] => 
    [post_modified_gmt] =>
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 
    [guid] => 
    [menu_order] =>
    [post_type] =>
    [post_mime_type] => 
    [comment_count] =>
    [filter] =>
)
```